# Magento // Get last created Product

Tags: magento, cart

hope someone can help me.

I got some Calculations running on my Cart to change the Price - that works very well.

BUT if I add the same Product twice in Cart, but with different Custom Option Values - the first Products options value will be overwritten by the option values of the second one....

Well...not so good!

I don´t know how to figure that out...
So I did some dirty stuff and clone every Product which is moving to Cart - so i have a new Product_ID and my calculations should run the right way because i think the Problem is that the first product values gets just overwritten by the second one because its the same Product Id.......

So now what i want :

_1 Option : I need to get my calculations running without changing the Price of the first Product when same Product_ID is in Cart

or

_2 Option : I need to load the Cloned Products in Cart instead of the original ones and show them up.

Any Ideas?

Cartcontroller.php

```
   /**
         * if customer enteres shopping cart we should mark quote
         * as modified bc he can has checkout page in another window.
         */
        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        Varien_Profiler::start(__METHOD__ . 'cart_display');
        $this
            ->loadLayout()
            ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
            ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
            ->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Shopping Cart'));
        $this->renderLayout();
        Varien_Profiler::stop(__METHOD__ . 'cart_display');
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_read");
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * CLONE PRODUCT
             */
            $clone=$product->duplicate();
            $clone->setSku($clonedSku);
            $clone->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);   
            $clone->setStatus(1); // AKTIV=1
            $clone->setVisibility(4);
            $clone->setTaxClassId(2);
            $clone->setCategoryIds("93");
            /**
             * Check product availability
             */ 
            if (!$clone) {
                $this->_goBack();
                return;
            }

            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }


            $cart->save();



            ################## table from which to get percent sku catalog_product_option_type_value & catalog_product_option
            foreach($this->_getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) 
            {           
                if($item->getProductId() == $product->getId()) 

                {   
                    $percentage_total = 0;
                    $optionsArray = array();
                    foreach($params['options'] as $key => $value){
                        $qry = "SELECT `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_type_id`, `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` ,`catalog_product_option_type_price`.`price` FROM `catalog_product_option_type_price` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_value` ON `catalog_product_option_type_price`.`option_type_id` = `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_type_id` AND `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`sku` = 'percent' AND `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_type_id` = '".$value."' AND `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` = '".$key."'";
                        $percentvalue = $connection->fetchAll($qry);
                        if(intval($percentvalue[0]['price'])>0) $optionsArray[] = $percentvalue[0];
                    }
                    if(count($optionsArray)>0)
                    {
                        $rowTotal = $item->getRowTotalInclTax();
                        $newTotal = $rowTotal;// - $percentage_total;
                        $newTotalGrand = 0;
                        foreach($optionsArray as $optionsArr)
                        {
                            $newTotalGrand += $optionsArr['price'];
                        }
                        if($newTotalGrand>0)
                        {

                            $newTotalGrand = ($newTotal/100)*$newTotalGrand;
                            $newTotal = $newTotal + $newTotalGrand;
                            $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET `custom_price` = '".$newTotal."',`original_custom_price` = '".$newTotal."' WHERE `sales_flat_quote_item`.`item_id` ='".$item->getId()."'";
                            $connection->query($query);
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
                        $clone->setPrice($newTotal);
            $clone->getResource()->save($clone);





            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When Magento adds products to the cart, it first performs a lookup to see if the product has already been added and simply increases the quantity. As you mention, this does not help when adding the same product with different custom options.

I found a way to do this very manually. Be sure to replace `$YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE` with your custom options and grabbing the correct product

```
// be sure to load the correct product
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart");
$cart->init();

$options = new Varien_Object(array("options" => $YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE,
                                   "qty" => 1));

$addall = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
  ->prepareForCartAdvanced($YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE, $product, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::PROCESS_MODE_FULL);
$addme = array_shift($addall);
```

Manually create a new sales quote item for the cart

```
$item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
$item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$item->setProduct($addme)
 ->setOptions($addme->getCustomOptions());
```

Manually add this to the quote (cart)

```
$item->setQty(1);
$cart->getQuote()->addItem($item);
```

After adding everything you want to add

```
$cart->save();
```

Comment: Well I think you didnt get my point :-/

My Problem is not that Magento just adds qty + 1 when i´m adding the same Product with other custom options.

I have 2 items on cart when i add a Product with different options.

My Problem is that when I´m adding the second one (same product but different options) to cart - the total of the first product gets overwritten by the second one.

I need magento to handle each Product as unique!

When I clone the Product and add this, there are no problems.

Comment: the total gets overwritten - do you meant the price? Do you have a demo to lookat? You can use the above to set a custom price on the product as well